# How to create the two json file from same class with different fields

Tags: java, json, jackson, jaxb

In my application i need to create the two json file from same object(object contain input + output fields)
Json file - 1: This json file should contain only input fields.
Json file - 2: This json file should contain few input fields and all output fields.

Let me explain with small example

below is the class from which i wants to generate the two json file

```
Class AreaDTO {
 String id;
 String name;
 String streetName;
 Street output;
}
```

```
json file 1     |   json file 2
{               |   {
  id            |       id
  name          |       name
  streetName    |       output
}              |    }
```

To creating object to json file currently i am using jackson,
How to achieve my above requiremnet with jackson or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) annotation at the class level. Then set the fields to null which you don't need. Then Jackson will ignore the fields which are null.

Please check https://mkyong.com/java/jackson-how-to-ignore-null-fields/

One more option is to use a custom JSON filter. Use Jackson to only serialize a field if it meets a specific, custom criteria.

Please check https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria

Comment: My object contain all value at one time, i can not make them null because it is used by other process at same time.

Comment: you can use custom @JsonFilter and define the custom logic accordingly.